# How to fit dmath equation into a block in beamer?

Tags: beamer, equations, block, multline

I am trying to fit a long equation into the `beamer` block:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}      % to fit content into a box

% Resize equations to always fit into frame:
\usepackage{environ}         % provides \BODY
\usepackage{etoolbox}        % provides \ifdimcomp
\usepackage{graphicx}        % provides \resizebox
\usepackage{breqn}           % for multi-line equations
###

\begin{frame}{Damping} 
    \begin{columns} 
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[ht]
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{images/sdof_damped}
            \end{center}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{block}<5->{Solution}     
            \begin{dmath*}
                x(t) =  \exp (-\zeta \omega_0 t) \left(  \frac{v_0 + \zeta \omega_0 x_0}{\omega_d} \sin \left( \omega_d t \right) + x_0 \cos \left( \omega_d t \right)  \right)
            \end{dmath*}
        \end{block}
        
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        # stuff goes here 
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, the equation exceeds the size of the block:

[image]

Would anyone be able to advise how to reduce the size of `dmath` equation such that it fits within the block in the `beamer`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where is defined `dmath*`? Please extend yout code fragment to complete small document ! You need to make your equation much smaller ...

Comment: Your MWE has errors and after correcting them it doesn't not reproduce showed image (Missed is used beamer theme).

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on [`breqn`](//ctan.org/pkg/breqn) to properly break the equation. Instead, break things manually within an `align*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Damping} 
  \begin{columns} 
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}

    \begin{block}{Solution}     
      \begin{align*}
        x(t) &= \exp (-\zeta \omega_0 t) \\
             &\qquad \biggl( \frac{v_0 + \zeta \omega_0 x_0}{\omega_d} \sin \bigl( \omega_d t \bigr) \\
             &\qquad\qquad + x_0 \cos \bigl( \omega_d t \bigr)  \biggr)
      \end{align*}
    \end{block}
    
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    More stuff goes here 
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked after adding \small :)

Comment: I agree! In general I'm suspicious about the results with `breqn`; in a `beamer` frame one should be very careful when splitting equations across lines: the frame will be visible only for a short time and the audience has short time to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

- You should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `end{document}`.
- As I already mentioned in comment, your equation is to big that can be fit in one column. A solution can be split it into two lines and make first factor shorter with writing as `mathrm{e}^{-\zeta \omega_0 t}`, for example as is done in MWE below.
- For fraction I suggest to use `\mfrac` which is defined in the `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Damping}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[ht]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%{images/sdof_damped}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{block}<2->{Solution}\small
        \begin{multline*}
            x(t) =  \mathrm{e}^{-\zeta \omega_0 t} 
                \Bigl(\mfrac{v_0 + \zeta \omega_0 x_0}{\omega_d}
                    \sin(\omega_d t)\\ + 
                x_0 \cos(\omega_d t)  
                \Bigr)
        \end{multline*}
        \end{block}

         \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \# stuff goes here
        
        \medskip
        \lipsum[66]
     \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addednum:**
A version when in equation is used normal font size and equation is aligned to left border of column (by use of `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}  % stolen from @Werner answer ...
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Damping}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[ht]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%{images/sdof_damped}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{block}<2->{Solution}
        \begin{fleqn}
        \begin{multline*}
            x(t) =  \mathrm{e}^{-\zeta \omega_0 t} 
                \Bigl(\mfrac{v_0 + \zeta \omega_0 x_0}{\omega_d}
                    \sin(\omega_d t)\\ + 
                x_0 \cos(\omega_d t)  
                \Bigr)
        \end{multline*}
        \end{fleqn}
        \end{block}

         \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \# stuff goes here
        
        \medskip
        \lipsum[66]
     \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that worked. The key seemed to be adding \small before the equation.

Comment: @Stefan, no. The key is breaking equation into two lines. See addendum to answer, where is used normal font size.